# Loading cursor being shown when a userform is called from another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform1 which calls another userform2 to accept some data. Once i successfully unload userform 2 the control is back to userform 1. However i am noticing the blue loading cursor (rotating one). At that time nothing works in userform 1. but its normal as soon as i click somewhere in the sheet.

It doesnt seems to be a huge problem as my forms are still working. But its bothering me enough to feel that i am not doing smthing correctly while closing like any property to be set etc.

Somemore info - Userform 2 can be accessed by Userform 1 and 3. The scenario which i mentioned about loading cursor is happening when Userform 1 calls userform 2 and agentupdateflag will be FALSE during that and true when screen is invoked by Userform 3

Code where userform 2 is called

```
Private Sub agentname_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    agentupdateflag = False
    On Error Resume Next
    userform2.Show
End Sub
```

Userform 2 initialization code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

agentstatus.AddItem ("Active")
agentstatus.AddItem ("Inactive")

If agentupdateflag = True Then
    Userform2.Agentid.Caption = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 0)
    Userform2.Agentname.value = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 1)
    Userform2.agentaddr.value = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 2)
    Userform2.agentcontact.value = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 3)
    Userform2.agentstatus.value = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 5)
    Userform2.agentidproof.value = Userform3.agentlist.List(Updateval, 6)
    Userform2.Caption = "Update Agent Details"
    addagent.Caption = "Update Agent"
    agentstatus.Locked = False
Else
    agentstatus.value = "Active"
    agentstatus.Locked = True
End If

End Sub
```

Userform 2 termination code where there is some processing

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

If agentupdateflag = False Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo err1
    Userform1.agentname.Clear
    j = 2
    Set ShDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Agent_info_Temp")
    Final_lastrow = ShDest.Cells(ShDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Final_lastcol = ShDest.Cells(1, ShDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ShDest.Activate

    With Userform1.agentname
        Do While j <= Final_lastrow
            If Trim(ShDest.Range("a" & j).value) <> "" Then
            .AddItem (ShDest.Range("a" & j).value & " - " & ShDest.Range("B" & j).value)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Userform1.agentname.ListIndex = Userform1.agentname.ListCount - 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Unload Me
Else
    'Unload Me
    Call Userform3.searchagent_Click
End If
'Unload Me

err1:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
            & Err.Source & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Contact System Admin."
    MsgBox Msg, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Critical System Error Encountered !", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and provide the relevant code example how you load and close the userform2 from userform1 so we can reproduce it. Without seeing what exactly you have done it is almost impossible to help.

Comment: FWIW, I've noticed that the cursor wait state has been kind of messed up in Windows 10 in general (not just in VBA). If everything else is functioning correctly, I'd probably just ignore it.

Comment: Updated the code info